# JavaScript is not working properly when I load from another page

Tags: javascript

When I load javascript from a seprate file it is not working properly but when I load same script from within the pa

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
 var p = document.querySelector("p");
 button.addEventListener("click",function(){
  p.textContent = "Someone Clicked";
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="listen.js"></script>
  <a href="https://www.google.co.in">My Link</a>
  <img src="logo.png">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>No one Has Clicked yet!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

ge it works correctly.

Comment: We cannot really help you without more information but my guess is that you are putting your script before your DOM. The page renders in order, top to bottom. Your Javascript file should below the dom that it interacts with. If your script tag is above the elements you are trying to use then `document.querySelector("button")` will return undefined which will cause `button.addEventListener` to throw an exception. Check the console (F12)

Comment: Try adding 
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading js file in the header and selecting button and p tag which are not present DOM at that time. either you can load your script in bottom of your page like this:

```
 `<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.co.in">My Link</a>
    <img src="logo.png">
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <p>No one Has Clicked yet!</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="listen.js"></script>
  </body>`
```

or you can put your script in window.onload() function. It will wait for page to load and then it will run your code.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    var p = document.querySelector("p");
    button.addEventListener("click",function(){
      p.textContent = "Someone Clicked";
    });
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank You very much